Azure Fabric shortcuts - some dataverse entities not visible
I am using Azure Fabric to obtain data from a number of sources, including a dataverse behind Dynamics 365.
I have been able to create shortcuts to a number of entities in my lakehouse.
The problem is quite a few entities are not visible in list of entities available to create a shortcut for.
Campaign is an example, I can see it in the Dataverse, I can connect to it via the Dataverse connector in Power BI & data-flows, but it is not available to create a shortcut against.
Is this a limitation of shortcuts, or is there potentially a setting i should look at to make the entity available for creating shortcuts against?

Do those missing tables have 'track-changes' enabled? or created when link to Fabric was in preview? It seems there are some limits.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/azure-synapse-link-view-in-fabric

Yes, track changes is ticked

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79264233/fo-tables-are-not-created-in-fabric this help? its a similar question
