F&O tables are not created in Fabric
We have set up an Azure Synapse Link for Dataverse in Fabric which is working fine. However, if we are adding tables from F&O, those tables are synced, but not created and hence not visible in Fabric.
In the Azure Synapse Link we can see this status:

Anyone has this before? Is this a specific setting that has to be turned on?
The row version change tracking is enabled for these tables
Thanks !

Issue is resolved!
If somebody has the same issue:
After the whole sync I had to manually trigger the button "Refresh Fabric Tables"
After couple of minutes, the tables were created in MS Fabric.
